# SQL Server database change in to single user type and We cannot access the tables

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Our team is working on a database and before some time it change to single user type and we cannot access any tables. Any idea what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has changed the database to single-user manually only one connection to the database is allowed. Everyone with ALTER permissions can do that (a reason why db_owner shouldn't be given to each and every user). Check the error log for any reason why the database is in single-user mode and make it available again:

```
ALTER DATABASE <databasename> SET MULTI_USER;
```